# How to Create 'Virtual Field' in CakePHP ver. 1.2

Tags: php, cakephp, model, pagination, virtual

**BELOW IS JUST AN UNDERSTANDABLE EXAMPLE TO MY PROBLEM**

"I have a table named '*homes*' linked to model '*Home*' having fields *id,title,price.*

I want to create a virtual field named 'calculated_price' which is based on some complex calculation which varies for USER TO USER depending on the search conditions for a particular record.

After that I want to paginate the model '*Home*' using

```
$this->paginate('Home',array('order'=>'calculated_price ASC'));
```

"

I have an ongoing enhancement project which use Cake version 1.2 that do not support 'virtual_field' concept as supported by Cake Ver 1.3

So please provide a solution to this....

How do I paginate & 'order by' a field which created dynamically using cakephp $this->paginate();

How/Can we tweak cake 1.2 to support virtual field concept of cake 1.3  ?OR is there any better solution?

Comment: [Migrating from CakePHP 1.2 to 1.3](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1561/Migrating-from-CakePHP-1-2-to-1-3)

Comment: Is there a way this calculated price can be calculated in SQL? e.g. SUM(field1, field2)

Answer (score 0):

If the calculation is made on runtime for each visualization why don't you just use `$this->set('calulated_price'=>calculated_price);`
?

Comment: Or maybe it can be a field in the users table?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution:

Create a "non-virtual" field in the users table, where you calculate the price via model callback methods e.g. afterSave()